# Is there a way to view all routes in a Hapi server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

We are working on a node.js Hapi server that pulls in a list of routes from a MongoDB database and sets up said routes for servicing. With this, there is the potential for the server to fail because of duplicate route entries in the database.

I've tried to look, but have failed to find a way to check for duplicate routes in Hapi.

Is it possible to get a list of routes a Hapi server is currently serving?

Is there an error check I can make that is prettier than a standard try/catch block when attempting to build the routes coming from the MongoDB?

The code that sets up the routes is below; please see my comments in the code for where I need to handle the error.

```
MySchema.find({}, function (err, stubs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error while loading');
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < stubs.length; i++) {
        var bodyMessage = stubs[i].body;

        // This is where we can fail, if only I could make a 
        // check for the route here
        server.route({
            method:  stubs[i].method,
            path: stubs[i].path,

            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply(bodyMessage);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Maybe [`server.table()`](http://hapijs.com/api#servertablehost) would help you? It returns a copy of the routing table.

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoMedeiros, I will try this tonight and let you know if it works. If it does, you should post it as an answer!

Comment: That did the trick! I can access it via server.table()[i].path, etc. now. @RodrigoMedeiros

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe [`server.table()`](https://hapi.dev/api/#-servertablehost) would help you? It returns a copy of the routing table. An example from the docs page:

```
var table = server.table()
console.log(table);

/*  Output:

    [{
      method: 'get',
      path: '/test/{p}/end',
      settings: {
        handler: [Function],
        method: 'get',
        plugins: {},
        app: {},
        validate: {},
        payload: { output: 'stream' },
        auth: undefined,
        cache: [Object] }
    }] */
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Hapi v17.6.0:

```
server.table().forEach((route) => console.log(`${route.method}\t${route.path}`));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Hapi version 15.1.1
and that's what works for me:

```
 // server.select if you have more than one connection
 const table = server.select('api').table();
 let routes = [];
 table[0].table.forEach((route) => { 
   // you can push here the route to routes array
   routes.push(route);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify a specific route you can look them up by key with the .match() method inside a connections obj.

```
var routeObj = server.connections[0].match('get', '/example', '<optional host>')
routeObj.settings.handler = function(req, reply){
  reply({"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"})
}
```

If you have multiple connections loop through them to change in each.
The above changes a routes handler to 404 since you are not supposed to remove routes.

Routes are stored in an object indexed by path in hapi/node_modules/call